# Dynamic CSV file download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv

In an MVC project, I have an ActionLink, which, when clicked, should take an arbitrary number of objects associated with the user (supplied as a List), dynamically build a CSV file of the objects' attributes and prompt a download. The file shouldn't persist on the server, so it either needs to be removed after download or the download needs to come from a stream or similar. What's the neatest way of going about this? I've seen examples of this which manually compile a CSV string and use `HttpResponse.Write(String)` within the controller, but is this best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a function that is similar to this.  I'm sure there is a "better" way to automatically find each of the members of the User object you pass it, but this way works.

```
    public ActionResult ExportCSV(List<User> input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                foreach (User user in input)
                {
                    writer.Write(user.firstattribute);
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(user.secondattribute);
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(user.thirdattribute);
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(user.lastattribute);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }

                writer.Flush();
            }

            output.Position = 0;

            return Controller.File(output, "text/comma-separated-values", "report.csv");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, this method assumes each attribute is a simple string with no commas in it

Answer (score 3):

If you have the stream, [returning a `FileStreamResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) is probably the "cleanest" way to do it in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually assemble a string, then `return Content(str, "text/csv");`

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx) is reportedly a nice library for generating CSV content.  Once you generate your CSV, use the `File` method of `Controller` to return a `FileStreamResult` from your action; that lets you send any arbitrary stream as a response, whether it's a `FileStreamResult` or any other type of `Stream`.